# how to execute parent process after child process has exited?

Tags: c, multiprocessing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pid_t childpid = 0; 
   int i, n;

   if (argc != 2){    
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
      return 1; 
   }     
   n = atoi(argv[1]);  
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
      if (childpid = fork()) 
         break;

   if (childpid>0){ // parent process
      while (i>1) {
        wait(NULL);
        i--;
      }
   }

   fprintf(stderr, "i:%d  process ID:%ld  parent ID:%ld  child ID:%ld\n",
           i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
   return 0; 
}
```

How I can print process information (parent) after all child process got exited in this code.

output:

```
i:1  process ID:2313  parent ID:2307  child ID:2314
i:3  process ID:2315  parent ID:2314  child ID:0
i:1  process ID:2314  parent ID:1  child ID:2315
```

I need child process to exit first and then parent process needs to print its process information.

Answer (score 4):

Make the wait tracking loop more informative and more thorough.  In particular, on the first cycle through the loop, the parent process has `n == 1`, so it never waits.  It is probably better to repeatedly wait until there are no more children to wait for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    int i, n;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s processes\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Creating %d sub-processes\n", n);
    fflush(stdout);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((childpid = fork()) != 0)
            break;
    }

    printf("%d: i = %d, childpid = %d\n", (int)getpid(), i, childpid);

    if (childpid != 0)
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    }

    printf("i: %d  process ID: %5ld  parent ID: %5ld  child ID: %5ld\n",
            i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)childpid);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (program compiled as `fork73`):

```
$ fork73 4
Creating 4 sub-processes
62621: i = 1, childpid = 62622
62622: i = 2, childpid = 62623
62623: i = 3, childpid = 62624
62624: i = 4, childpid = 0
i: 4  process ID: 62624  parent ID: 62623  child ID:     0
62623: child 62624 exited with status 0x0000
i: 3  process ID: 62623  parent ID: 62622  child ID: 62624
62622: child 62623 exited with status 0x0000
i: 2  process ID: 62622  parent ID: 62621  child ID: 62623
62621: child 62622 exited with status 0x0000
i: 1  process ID: 62621  parent ID:   877  child ID: 62622
$
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your program is this statement -

```
if (childpid = fork())
```

Because of this, the parent process exits the loop in the first iteration as `fork()` returns child process PID to it and child process proceed with executing the loop as `fork()` returns 0 to it. That's why in your output you are getting a child process (PID - 2314) as parent of process (PID - 2315) -

```
i:1  process ID:2313  parent ID:2307  child ID:2314
i:3  process ID:2315  parent ID:2314  child ID:0
```

The correct statement is -

```
if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
```

Comment: When you say that the `if (childpid = fork())` statement causes the parent to exit the loop, you are of course correct.  But that isn't necessarily wrong.  It depends on the process structure that's wanted.  As it stands, the parent creates a child, which creates a grand child, which creates a great grand child, … Your alternative will create a bunch of sibling child processes for the parent process.  Both are (or either is) correct — if that's what you want.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much for elucidating the other aspect of the question asked. I answered this question with the thought in mind - a parent process and bunch of sibling child process because in the question it has been mentioned  - "print process information (parent) after **all** child process got exited in this code". But I completely agree with you, both are correct as it depends on process structure that's wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer is useful because it covers an option or alternative that I didn't.